# Adding groovy file from workspace for seed job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a seed job in Jenkins to create a job to build the workspace. I want to add the job groovy file from the repository. How do I specify the file path for the grooovy on the seed job build step?

I am trying to add it from the file system on the configuration. I get the error file not found. I have tried adding the complete path and also the name of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for it.

You can specify just the relative path to the workspace to access the groovy files.